# Cronjob for taking all MySQL database and sending it to e-mail

Tags: php, mysql, cron

I want to create cronjob which would execute .php file and that file would get all database and that databe would be sent directly to my e-mail every day.

Have any ideas how could I do that?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

What do you mean, "all database"? You want a listing of the databases held within the server? A dump of their contents? You don't need PHP for that, you can simply use a shell script:

```
mysqldump -p -u username_to_do_dump_with --all-databases | mail you@example.com -s 'database dumps'
```

In short: dump all databases held within mysql, pipe that output to the mail program, which sends the dump to you.

Of course, if you have a lot of data (particularly if you're storing files in the database), you're going to end up with a huge email, and emailing could corrupt the dump if there's any binary data. You'd most likely want to run the dump through gzip to reduce its side, and then have that .gz file sent out as an attachment, which would take a bit more scripting that this very simple version.

Comment: @Marc B: it doesn't send me a file, it gives only text : <br /><br />/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;

Comment: Although it doesn´t answer the OP's question, I´d just dump it, gzip it and rsync it to another machine. Mail doesn´t seem the right medium for a backup...

Comment: @hey: dump to a file, gzip it, then use a bit more shell scripting to send the file as attachment. But like I said in my answer, you don't need PHP for this - a simple shell script can do this far easier than PHP could.

Comment: @Marc B: ok, what shell script should I use? The one you gave, send only some text, not file.

Comment: `mysqldump blah blah | gzip -9 > file.gz ; mutt -a file.gz "attachment" you@example.com`

Comment: @Marc B: it gives me an error: "sh: mutt: command not found". In addition to this, maybe I should change "blah blah" to something?

Comment: That was just an example - you'd have to install mutt (a mail client), or something similar which can send attachments from the command line. And yes, blah blah should be something else.

Comment: @Marc B: or maybe I am able without any installments save mysql backup directly to ftp? What code should I write then?

Comment: ftp can't stream a file. You'd still have to dump to a file, then ftp that. You could use something like scp: `mysqldump blah blah | gzip -9 | ssh user@somehost.com "echo > file.sql.gz"`. But then you'd have to enter your credentials each time you do this, set up key-based access, or store your credentials in a keychain.

Answer (score 2):

You could just write a script that does a mysqldump and then emails you the file... Are you actually asking someone to give you such a script or are you asking how to put it into cron?

Comment: @hey I would use Marc B's solution, and stick it into cron (using crontab -e) using another person's solution :D

Answer (score 0):

Include the following in your crontab

@daily php php_file.php | mail -E -s "Subject line" your@emailaddress.com

mail is a program to send emails, it reads the body text from stdin and -s defines the subject line. -E means only send an email if there is body text, you may or may not want this.

Answer (score 0):

Well you would write the php script, first.

Then you would put a line in your crontab something like this:

`1     1     *   *    *        path/to/your/script`

To run the script once a day.